# Finding Average of two numbers C++

Tags: c++

As a newbie in the world of programming, I have to write a bit of C++ code to find the average of two numbers.
However, my code somehow appears to be incorrect. Please take a look at my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  float a, b, average; 

  cin >> a;
  cin >> b;

  average = (a+b)/2;

  cout << average << endl;
}
```

however, it says I am wrong because when I input 10 10 it outputs 10 but the system wants me to output 10.00

Comment: What is the difference between 10 and 10.00 mathematically? Can you output a number (e.g. float) and get 10.00?

Comment: @QuantumPi Did any of the answers help to solve the problem?

Answer (score 5):

You need to use some I/O manipulators.
[`std::setprecision`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) and [`std::fixed`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed)

Example:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    if(float a, b; std::cin >> a >> b) {
        float average = (a+b)/2;

        std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << average << '\n';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Like others have said you need to change your cout line to:

`cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << average << endl;`

Remember that with the `<<`s you're putting a stream of data (an iostream) into cout. The first piece of data is `std::fixed` which says "Display floats to a fixed number of decimal places, don't cut off any trailing zeros." And then `std::setprecision(2)` says "Make that fixed number of decimal places 2." You could use an int variable or another number in place of 2 if you wanted. From there the stream has your average and an endline like before.

Comment: Good explanation. Though, "_putting a stream of data (an iosteam) into cout_" is a bit confusing. `cout` is an `ostream` (not an `iostream`) and the data is not a stream. Other than that, good. +1 from me.

Answer (score 1):

Set decimal precision
Sets the decimal precision to be used to format floating-point values on output operations.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <iomanip>      // std::setprecision

int main() {
  float a, b, average; 

  cin >> a;
  cin >> b;

  average = (a+b)/2;

  cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << average << endl;
}
```